# Is iOS, Android binded libraries in Xamarin working in all devices(WinPhone, iOS, Android)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Sorry for may be stupid question, I’m novice and never had experience with compiled languages.
I have library for iOS(VideoCore) and want to start to write mobile application in C# and use Xamarin for it, but will this imported library work on Windows Phone or in Android version of my mobile application, or I need to find alternative library in C#?

Comment: No, afaik, only C# code can be shared between platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VideoCore is an iOS-only framework, so you'll need to find alternatives for Android and Windows Phone.

You don't say what you're wanting to use VideoCore for, so it's hard to suggest alternatives. For video processing on Android, have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

Comment: Hi! I knew about alternative, I was planning to use it for streaming video to remote media server. I found already streaming libraries for all platforms, but i was searching one common which I could share between platforms. Thanks for response.